# Creating table pointing to multiple sub folder in S3 bucket using AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-athena

Is there an option to create a table pointing to multiple s3 bucket subfolders.

Example:

s3://athena-my-bucket/Test/location1 and s3://athena-my-bucket/Test/location2 there are few folders like location3, location4, location5, but I want to create table only pointing to these two subfolders on the s3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to define a table with fake partitioning column and register two distinct locations as two partitions, arguably simpler approach is:

- define a table for each of these two locations
- create a view that UNION ALLs these two tables

Comment: This is just an example if in case I want to fetch the detail from more subfolders is there an option. Your solution is helpful only in case I want to fetch from only two folders what I would need to merge a week logs or two weeks logs.

Comment: It's applicable to any small number of folders. How many folders do you expect to be querying?

Comment: In my case, I might look for 2 weeks logs where the subfolders are separate by days like day=1, day=2 day=3, so might need to create individual tables for each folder.

Comment: Seems like you will need some automation for this anyway. Then it should not matter whether this is 2 or 14 folders.

Comment: if you have a format like day=1 , day=2 - then this is the correct format for partitoning and new folder would show up automatically if you execute MSCK REPAIR (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/msck-repair-table.html)